# Is there a mature implementation of the FNV hashing algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, fnv

I've seen the Fowler-Noll-Vo (FNV) recommended as a good choice for a fast hashing algorithm for use in our implementation of a consistent hashing system.

Can't seem to locate a good Java source for it though.

Comment: Where can we see more about the FLV-1 hash alg?

Comment: I can't find any hash algorithms named FLV with google. Are you sure you don't mean FNV?

Comment: http://www.last.fm/user/RJ/journal/2007/04/10/rz_libketama_-_a_consistent_hashing_algo_for_memcache_clients

My bad. The source was a comment in this web page. Seems to have been a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find Java sources at [getopt.org](http://www.getopt.org/).

Comment: I would add that you should consider this comment: "This is a very fast hash, with excellent avalanche behavior. Compared with the FNV1a32 (see below) it's roughly 10 times faster, and roughly 5 times faster that a Java version of Jenkins' hash ( available here).
This implementation is a Java port of a C version of MurmurHash 2.0 ."

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk That comment was for MurmurHash not for FNV